# Material UI Tooltip inside custom container

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, material-ui

I am developing a chrome extension using React and Material UI. I am using an inject page strategy. I am display tooltip for the Fab button but it is showing outside my extension DOM. I see in the inspect element that it is appending to the body. **How do I define placement container for my tooltip to be in my extension div?**

Here is the inspect element. As seen tooltip div is appended to body. My extension div is the div of my extension.

[image]

Here is the code

```
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

<Tooltip title="Dialpad">
    <Fab color="primary" size="medium" aria-label="add" className={classes.fab}>
        <DialpadIcon />
    </Fab>
</Tooltip>
```

my-extension-root is the div of my extension page.

Comment: Please provide some code / images / working example. Otherwise it's really hard to help.

Comment: See edits of question

Answer (score 0):

Create a ref to container element where you want to place the tooltip code in the dom and then use PopperProps to assign that container to your tooltip as shown in the following code.

Create Ref.

```
const containerElement = useRef()
```

Assign ref to the container element.

```
return (<div ref={containerElement}>
.
.
.
</div>)
```

Assign the container element to the tooltip with the help of ref.

```
<Tooltip title="Dialpad" PopperProps={{container: containerElement.current}}>
    <Fab color="primary" size="medium" aria-label="add" className={classes.fab}>
        <DialpadIcon />
    </Fab>
</Tooltip>
```